# How do I unarchive archived files using NSKeyedArchive?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I've got some questions when I'm coding the sample source.

This is my code.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        NSDictionary *glossary = [
            NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                  @"A class defined so other classes can inherit from it",
                                  @"abstract class",
                                  @"To implement all the methods defined in a protocol",
                                  @"adopt",
                                  @"Storing an object for later use",
                                  @"archiving"
                                  , nil

        ];


        //archiving
        [NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:glossary toFile:@"glossary.archive"];

        //unarchiving?


    }
    return 0;
}
```

and My Book suggests the following code to unarchive "glossary"

```
glossary = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:@"glossary.archive"];
```

But, there is no class named "unarchiveObjectWithFile"...

---

I have two question for solving this problem.

**First.** Apple developer documentation specified about "unarchive~" . If so, is there a problem with autocomplete function? //edit

my autocomplete function suggest only "classForKeyedUnarchiver"

**Second.** If not, I wondering what class can I use instead "unarchive~".

Thanks for your reading.

Comment: Alcatraz plug-in is not something that everybody knows of.

Comment: Sorry. i was mistaken for the Alcatraz was offered autocomplete function. I corrected the question